# Pass row index to event handler in data table

Tags: angular, primeng

I use a data table from PrimeNG and have the following template code:

```
<p-column [style]="{'width':'40px'}">
    <template let-col let-rowData="rowData" let-rowIndex="rowIndex" pTemplate type="body">
        <button type="text" pButton icon="fa-remove" style="height: 20px;  width: 25px"
       (click)="onDeleteDataProviderDefinitionClicked($rowIndex)">      </button>     
    </template>
</p-column>
```

I want to tell the event handler method "onDeleteDataProviderDefinitionClicked" which row index has been clicked. Therefore I tried to pass the respective rowIndex to its method signature. However, the value is later on undefined.

Any ideas how to accomplish it?

Answer (score 9):

Template Code

```
<p-column [style]="{'width':'40px'}">
<template let-col let-rowData="rowData" let-i="rowIndex" pTemplate type="body">
    <button type="text" pButton icon="fa-remove" style="height: 20px;  width: 25px"
   (click)="onDeleteDataProviderDefinitionClicked(i)">      </button>     
</template>
```

Typescript Code

```
onDeleteDataProviderDefinitionClicked(rowIndex) {
   console.log(rowIndex);
}
```

Comment: You are awesome

Comment: But i'm not sure what is the purpose of rowIndex in template? But it is working good.

Answer (score 2):

You have a redundant `$`:

```
(click)="onDeleteDataProviderDefinitionClicked(rowIndex)"
```

and not `$rowIndex`

The reason you see in the samples `$event` it is because it is a reserved word for the default event.